# OS disk type support during virtual machine provisioning in java sdk

Tags: azure, types, azure-virtual-machine, disk

Azure portal allows us to select the os disk type (HDD/SSD) while creating virtual machine. But when I try to deploy the virtual machine using java SDK there is no support available from the API to pass the disk type.

```
var linuxVM1 = azure.VirtualMachines
  .Define(linuxVM1Name)
  .WithRegion(Region.USEast)
  .WithNewResourceGroup(rgName)
  .WithNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
  .WithPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
  .WithNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress(linuxVM1Pip)
  .WithPopularLinuxImage(KnownLinuxVirtualMachineImage.UbuntuServer16_04_Lts)
  .WithRootUsername(“tirekicker”)
  .WithSsh(sshkey)
  .WithNewDataDisk(100)
  .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardD3V2)
  .Create();
```

Can anyone please provide me the pointer on how to set the disk type during virtual machine provisioning.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> can anyone please provide me the pointer on how to set the disk type during virtual machine provisioning.

If you want to select  os disk type (HDD/SSD) please append `.withOSDiskStorageAccountType(StorageAccountTypes.PREMIUM_LRS)`. **PREMIUM_LRS** means that uses the SSD disk. If you want to choose HDD disk you could use `StorageAccountTypes.STANDARD_LRS`. The following is the demo code.

```
var linuxVM1 = azure.VirtualMachines
  .Define(linuxVM1Name)
  .withRegion(Region.USEast)
  .withNewResourceGroup(rgName)
  .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
  .withPrimaryPrivateIpAddressDynamic()
  .withNewPrimaryPublicIpAddress(linuxVM1Pip)
  .withPopularLinuxImage(KnownLinuxVirtualMachineImage.UbuntuServer16_04_Lts)
  .withRootUsername(“tirekicker”)
  .withSsh(sshkey)
  .withOSDiskStorageAccountType(StorageAccountTypes.PREMIUM_LRS) //StorageAccountTypes.STANDARD_LRS
  .withNewDataDisk(100)
  .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardD3V2)
  .create();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: @Shaan If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.